# Empty confirmation mail with FOSUSER BUNDLE

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm beginner in Symfony2, I follow symfony documentation: [FOSUserBundle Emails](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md) for Registration and Confirmation, but I receive an empty mail.

I can create a new user and login, but the email confirmation is empty

Comment: Can you add the contents of your YAML file (or at least the relevant parts) to the question?

Comment: Are you sure it's symfony problem? Did you try to send mails using php on that server?

Comment: this is the contents of mail :registration.email.message

Comment: the problem is in : " php app/console cache:clear --env=prod  " so i delete the the contents of folder   Cache to clean the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in : " php app/console cache:clear --env=prod  " so i delete the the contents of folder   Cache to clean the cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
fos_user:
    registration:
         confirmation:
             enabled:    true
```

place it in your:: app/config/config.yml

Comment: I found the solution and the problem is in the cleaning of the cache so i delete the folder cache manually because the command :php app/console cache:clear --env=prod   not always functional.